# How to create link_to from Ruby/Non-ruby-mixed string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

In my view file (*.html.erb), I would like to create a link that shows two model datapoints (name and vote count). In the case of Bobby, who has five votes, it would look graphically like: 
[Bobby(5)](http://bobbysurl.com).

How do I do this with a link_to, given that the string I want to show includes non-ruby parentheses?

Before turning it into a link, the code is,

```
<%= user.name %>(<%= link.user.reputation_value_for(:votes).to_i %>)
```

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to "#{user.name}(#{user.reputation_value_for(:votes).to_i})", whatever_path %>
```

When building a string with ruby code in it, just type it normally and put the ruby code you need in between this: #{}

When the page loads, the erb is compiled first and in my string above

```
#{user.name}
```

will be replaced with Bobby and

```
#{user.reputation_value_for(:votes).to_i}
```

will be replace with 8 (if that's his reputation value) giving you

[Bobby(8)](http://bobbysurl.com)

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. It always seems so easy once you've seen the answer... :)

Answer (score 1):

`link_to` is able to accept blocks, like:

```
<%= link_to user do %>
    <%= user.name %>(<%= link.user.reputation_value_for(:votes).to_i %>)
<% end %>
```

Comment: this is interesting. Didn't know that this was an option. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to consider an MVC approach, putting the logic to calculate that in the model and calling it from the controller.

In this way I would start with the model.

I would consider User, Link and Votes models.  Votes would be the join table and would need a migration that would add the two foreign keys to it (`user_id` and `link_id`),

```
User
  has_many votes
  has_many :links, :through => :votes

Link
  has_many_votes
  has_many_users, :through => :votes
  def votes_by_user
    user.votes
  end

Vote
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :link
```

Then in the Link controller I would have

(in the show method for 1 link)

```
@link = Link.find(params[:id])
```

In the show view I would have:

```
@link.users.each do |one_user|    
  link_to one_user, "#{link.user.name}(#{link.votes_by_user(one_user)}")
end
```

For the index method for links wrap it all in an iteration through then, e.g.

(index method)

```
@links=Link.all
```

(view)

```
<%- @links.each do |one_link|  %>
  <%- one_link.users.each do |one_user| %>   
    <%= link_to one_user, "#{link.user.name}(#{link.votes_by_user(one_user)}") %>
  <%- end %>
<%- end %>
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I will consider moving the guts to the controller. I actually needed to figure out how to structure the string first!